# AWS Lambda: How to get environment variables

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Inside my **lambda_handler** function, how can I get the environment variables that I have defined?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     
    # Get environment variables (see screenshot below)   
    key1 = event[0]
    key2 = event[1]
    key3 = event[2]

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': key1
    }
```

**Environment Variables**
[image]

Comment: you can use import os; print(os.environ['variable'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not actually the environment variables, this is the event payload passed into the Lambda.

In your case you would access this by accessing its keys in the structure i.e. `event['key1']`. To reiterate this event contents are the payload passed in by the invoker (be that a service or the SDK).

[Environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) do exist in Lambda, but are accessed in the native way the language would access the environment variables.